# Cauchy-Schwarz inequality: product between two ordered sets

Tags: vector-spaces

We have two ordered sets: $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$.

To demonstrate the first triangular property of the ordered sets, we introduce another property called Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

$$-|u|\,|v| \leq \vec{u} \cdot \vec{v} \leq |u|\,|v|$$

So, can I write the product between $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ as this? The ordered sets are, in fact, vectors? So, is the first time I see vectorial product in this form

$$ \vec{u} \cdot \vec{v} = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n u_{i} \cdot v_{i} $$

Comment: That's usually called *scalar product*, and yes, the $n$-uples (a more common name than *ordered sets*) are vectors.

Comment: Thanks! I could not find a term to indicate, in English, those that in Italian are called "n-uple"

Answer (score 1):

The "multiplication" should hold $4$ conditions :

$1 ) <\alpha u,v> =\alpha <u,v> $

$2 ) <u_1 +u_2,v> = <u_1 ,v> + <u_2 ,v>$

$3 ) <u,v> = Conj <v, u> $

$4 ) <v,v> \geq 0 $ and $<v,v>=0 $ iff $ v =0$

So if we define $<u,v> = \sum u_i v_i $ and $u,v \in \mathbb{R^n}$, then all the above are true and thus we can use  Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, or Triangle inequality and all the other known inequalites and equations